# How to make sure Firebase fetches data from the server only

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to fetch data from Firebase server only and if there is no internet connection it should show a failure message.

```
  Source source = Source.SERVER;
  firebaseFirestore.collection("stock").document(pid).get(source).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                String prod_id = document.getString("pid");
                       }
                                
                    }
                });
```

I tried doing the above but it still loads cached results if there is no internet.

Please help.

Comment: You can use the connection state to detect when user is offline or not : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: @djleop That is only for Realatime Database.  There is no equivalent for Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson my bad... Those datastores are by the way not meant to be used with this "online only" constraint, reading docs it is not really obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to fetch data from firebase server only

This is exactly what your code does. By specifying `Source.SERVER`, you are telling Firestore to return only data from the server.

> if there is no internet connection it should show a failure message.

`onFailure()` fires **only** when there is a problem in reading documents, for example, when you don't have permission to access them. In other words, when Firebase server rejects the read operation due to the permissions that are set the in security rules. `onFailure()` will never fire when there is no internet connection on user device and it makes sense since you need to access the data while offline. This **cannot** be considered a failure.

> I tried doing the above but it still loads cached results if there is no internet.

That's normal behavior. The Firestore SDK caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline.

**Edit:**

According to @FrankvanPuffelen comment, in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source#public-static-final-source-server) is also mentioned that:

> **public static final Source SERVER**

> Causes Cloud Firestore to avoid the cache, **generating an error if the server cannot be reached**. Note that the cache will still be updated if the server request succeeds. Also note that latency-compensation still takes effect, **so any pending write operations will be visible in the returned data (merged into the server-provided data)**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My document keeps updating so what can I do to make sure the data I receive is the exact updated value?

Comment: There is nothing in your question/code related to some document updates. However, `onComplete()` method fires when the operation for getting data from the database is completed successfully.

Comment: @AlexMamo: it might help to include the definition from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source#public-static-final-source-server) in your answer: "Causes Cloud Firestore to avoid the cache, **generating an error if the server cannot be reached**. Note that the cache will still be updated if the server request succeeds. Also note that latency-compensation still takes effect, so **any pending write operations will be visible in the returned data (merged into the server-provided data)**."

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Right, puf, it's helpful. Just updated my answer. Thanks